# Inserting text at the cursor point - currently inserting into the clicked element not text field

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Found this function:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, html;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    range.insertNode(textNode);
    range.setStartAfter(textNode);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

I have a content editable div and a button set up to add an image tag into the div.

However, as per the fiddle, the button adds the text to itself and not the div.

Any help?

https://jsfiddle.net/e859j9an/

Comment: window.getSelection() is used for getting the selected text from the element. Since your source is the same the selection, it would end up appending the textnode to the same elements. Do you want to just add image tag to the div on click of the button ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I find a way to do it when you click in the contenteditable `div` :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e859j9an/6/)

I've updated your JS with this code :

```
$(function() {
  /* Text editor */   
  $(".custom-text-editor").on('click', function(){
    insertTextAtCursor('this text');
  });   
});

function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

I don't know if you can get the right position in the div.custom-text-editor when you click on the button ..

Comment: Hi thanks nope, want to be able to simple insert the text at the cursor point. Working on a Medium style text editor and for now its just text being insert but it will eventually be an image uploader.

Comment: I've edited it but i doubt you can get the right position in the contenteditable div if you click on an other button than to click in the div

Answer (score 0):

it is because when you click on another element,the contenteditable div loses it's focus.

change your code like this.

```
$(".custom-text-editor").focus();
$(".insert-image").on('mousedown', function(e){
insertTextAtCursor("this is an image");
return false;
});
```